# place button next to input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control"><button class="btn btn-primary">Absenden</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the button placed next to the input like it is on the following picture:[image]

Comment: Could we see what the listed styles are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `input-group` for this:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Abschicken</button>
  </span>
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

---

Du kannst `input-group` dafür nutzen:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Abschicken</button>
  </span>
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.form-control {
    display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s4392dc2/)